# Что за шины находится в каталогах /i2c-0/ — /i2c-N/?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, железо

В каталоге **/sys/bus/i2c/devices/** находятся каталоги **/i2c-0/** — **/i2c-N/**. Например, чтобы добраться до шины процессора, приходится инициализировать мультиплексор командой

```
echo "ltc4306 0x4e" > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device
```

Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли как-то узнать, что за шины находится в каталогах **/i2c-N/**? По аппаратной части достаточно много инфы в интернете, а вот описания программной нет.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "шиной процессора" и "шинами" в каталогах? По-моему вам стоит начать с азов принципа архитектуры шин master-slave, в частности I²C. https://i2c.info/i2c-bus-specification

Comment: @0andriy в принципе работы шины i2c я разобрался, вопрос в том, в данном примере каталог i2c-0 это только мультиплексор или через этот каталог можно инициализировать что-то еще поменяв подгружаемый модуль ядра и адрес. Вот именно это я не до конца понимаю.

Comment: @0andriy то есть нужно до конца понять чему на шине i2c соответсвуют каталоги i2c-0 - i2c-N.

Comment: Так это вам надо вначале со схемой разобраться. Или вы вслепую хотите? `i2cdetect` в помощь.